# Linear and Non-linear transformation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, linear-algebra

Where and why is linear and non-linear transformations is useful. What are use cases in Machine learning and in deep learning especially for computer vision.

Comment: Do you know for what linear transformation is used? Do you know how a computer sees (works with) pictures?

Comment: I know what is linear transformations are but don't know for what linear transformation is used for. Please point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A neural net can be seen as framework for linear transformation.
Think of the math operations which are defining the linear transformation and compare it with a neural net.